# Xamarin.Android Attach Fab Button to RecyclerView

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.ios

i'm working on **C# Xamarin.Android**

[GITHUB - jamesmontemagno/FloatingActionButton-for-Xamarin.Android](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/FloatingActionButton-for-Xamarin.Android)

this library is now deprecated, and i don't find how to attach my fab button to recyclerview: when is scroll up or down i want that the fab button appears and disappears..

This is how github code was. But today is not working

```
var listView = FindViewById<ListView>(Android.Resource.Id.list);
var fab = FindViewById<FloatingActionButton>(Resource.Id.fab);
fab.AttachToListView(listView);
```

My XML:

```
    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/buildpizzaingredienti_toolbar">
        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/buildpizzaingredienti_cmListView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_next"
        app:backgroundTint="#4A8E53" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an example how to add animation on `FloatingActionButton` [Animating an Android Floating Action Button](https://www.sitepoint.com/animating-android-floating-action-button/)
but I assumed maybe you would have problems with translation Java code in C# so I made it quickly.

```
class FAB_Hide_on_Scroll : FloatingActionButton.Behavior
{
    public FAB_Hide_on_Scroll(Context context, IAttributeSet attr) : base()
    {

    }
    public override void OnNestedScroll(CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout, Java.Lang.Object child, View target, int dxConsumed, int dyConsumed, int dxUnconsumed, int dyUnconsumed)
    {
        base.OnNestedScroll(coordinatorLayout, child, target, dxConsumed, dyConsumed, dxUnconsumed, dyUnconsumed);

        var fab = child.JavaCast<FloatingActionButton>();
        if (fab.Visibility == ViewStates.Visible && dyConsumed > 0)
        {
            fab.Hide();
        }
        else if (fab.Visibility == ViewStates.Gone && dyConsumed < 0)
        {
            fab.Show();
        }
    }
    public override bool OnStartNestedScroll(CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout, Java.Lang.Object child, View directTargetChild, View target, int nestedScrollAxes)
    {
        return nestedScrollAxes == ViewCompat.ScrollAxisVertical;
    }
}
```

Then you have to include this class in your `FloatingActionButton` behavior to get desired behavior. Like this:

`app:layout_behavior="com.yourpackagename.FAB_Hide_on_Scroll"`

I'm not sure does for your `Recyclerview` and `FloatingActionButton` container or parent has to be `CoordinatorLayout`. Just note that I didn't test this code so I don't know will it throw some errors you will have to do that.

Comment: I test your code, but when i compile I get two errors on override methods:

`xamarin onNestedScroll(CoordinatorLayout,View,View,int,int,int,int) in FAB_Hide_on_Scroll and onNestedScroll(CoordinatorLayout,V,View,int,int,int,int) in Behavior have the same erasure, yet neither overrides the other public void onNestedScroll (android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout p0, android.view.View p1, android.view.View p2, int p3, int p4, int p5, int p6) where V is a type-variable: V extends View declared in class Behavior`

Answer (score 0):

Update based on a newer version:

```
public class FabBehavior : CoordinatorLayout.Behavior
{
    public FabBehavior()
    {

    }

    public FabBehavior(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs) : base(context, attrs)
    {
    }

    public override void OnNestedScroll(CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout, Object child, View target, int dxConsumed, int dyConsumed, int dxUnconsumed,
        int dyUnconsumed, int type)
    {
        base.OnNestedScroll(coordinatorLayout, child, target, dxConsumed, dyConsumed, dxUnconsumed, dyUnconsumed, type);

        var fab = child.JavaCast<FloatingActionButton>();
        if (fab.Visibility == ViewStates.Visible && dyConsumed > 0)
        {
            fab.Hide(new VisibilityListener());
        }
        else if (fab.Visibility == ViewStates.Invisible && dyConsumed < 0)
        {
            fab.Show();
        }
    }

    public override bool OnStartNestedScroll(CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout, Object child, View directTargetChild, View target, int axes, int type)
    {
        return axes == ViewCompat.ScrollAxisVertical;
    }
}

public class VisibilityListener : FloatingActionButton.OnVisibilityChangedListener
{
    public override void OnHidden(FloatingActionButton fab)
    {
        base.OnHidden(fab);

        fab.Visibility = ViewStates.Invisible;
    }
}
```

Update:

I don't know why, but this class works:

`FabBehavior : CoordinatorLayout.Behavior`

Because `Hide()` set `ViewStates.Gone` to fab and `ConstraintLayout` not see anymore this button. Sad

Need to change `Gone` to `Invisible`

`if (fab.Visibility == ViewStates.Invisible && dyConsumed < 0)`

Need to add `VisivilityListener` for hidden action. Inside it's set `Invisible` instead `Gone`

`fab.Hide(new VisibilityListener());`

Comment: Can you clarify your explanation at the end of your answer? The code doesn't appear to be formatted correctly